# How to uninstall Postgis from windows?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to remove the `PostGIS` installation from my windows machine and install a fresh version.

I have tried the following so far but still when I re-install `postgresql` it shows that `PostGIS` is already installed

1. Uninstall `Postgresql` from the control panel.
2. Delete the `Postgresql` folder
3. Delete folders in `Registry Editor` on windows.

Can you please tell me how to remove `PostGIS` completely from the machine?

Comment: Have you tried `DROP EXTENSION postgis` before you uninstall your PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: No I have already uninstalled `PostgreSQL`. Do you think if I re-install `PostgreSQL` and run `DROP EXTENSION postgis` will uninstall `Postgis` from my Windows machine?

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I don't have a windows machine to test it myself, but it would be my first try:) good luck

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. I cannot drop extension postgis (ERROR: extension "postgis" does not exist)